# How to set default heading for ckeditor5?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, wysiwyg, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor5

I am using custom build BalloonEditor in my React project.

```
import { CKEditor } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import Editor from "ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor";

const editorConfiguration = {
  heading: {
    options: [
      { model: "paragraph", title: "Paragraph", class: "ck-heading_paragraph" },
      {
        model: "heading1",
        view: "h1",
        title: "Heading 1",
        class: "ck-heading_heading1",
      },
      {
        model: "heading2",
        view: "h2",
        title: "Heading 2",
        class: "ck-heading_heading2",
      },
      {
        model: "heading3",
        view: "h3",
        title: "Heading 3",
        class: "ck-heading_heading3",
      },
      {
        model: "heading4",
        view: "h4",
        title: "Heading 4",
        class: "ck-heading_heading4",
      },
      {
        model: "heading5",
        view: "h5",
        title: "Heading 5",
        class: "ck-heading_heading5",
      },
      {
        model: "heading6",
        view: "h6",
        title: "Heading 6",
        class: "ck-heading_heading6",
      },
    ],
  },
  toolbar: {
    items: ["bold", "italic", "underline", "link"],
  },
  placeholder: "Type the content here!",
  language: "en",
  licenseKey: "",
};

class TextBlock extends Component {
  handleChange = (event, editor) => {
    const data = editor.getData();
    // updating state with data
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <CKEditor
        editor={Editor}
        data={content}
        config={editorConfiguration}
        onChange={(event, editor) => this.handleChange(event, editor)}
        onReady={(editor) => {
          editor.execute("heading", { value: "heading2" });
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see i am not giving heading selection option in toolbar. By default ckeditor consider it as `<p> tag` but my aim is to set default heading as lets say `<h2>`.

While searching in [ckeditor documentation for heading](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/headings.html). I came across this code which i think can help me `editor.execute( 'heading', { value: 'heading2' } );` but i dont know where to place it currently I am using it in onReady props which is working as expected but sometimes it gives out the error `Uncaught TypeError: editor.execute is not a function`. I think I am doing something wrong here.

I am struggling with one more usecase with ckeditor5. Please help if possible.
while we are typing in ckeditor and hit enter/return it makes a new `<p> tag` whereas I want it to be `<br> tag`. Is it possible?

Thank you for your time.